# Which database for standalone java program?

Tags: java, database

I want to develop a java swing application with database access.
May i know which database should i use?

So far i only know to use database like mysql, oracle...
but these database need to be install,host,configure..etc

Can a database be store as a file? and put inside my app's directory so that it is delivered together with my program.

The user only have to download and run the program, and the database is working (similar with sqlite in android application）.

Comment: Search for [embedded database](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=java+embedded+database). H2, HSql, Derby, ...

Comment: Also, SQLite can be used in plain java applications too

Comment: seems like, you are asking for embedded database.